# [UITableView setEmptyDataSetSource:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am trying to use DZNEmptyDataSet, i created the pods and did everything right but when i added the below to my viewDidLoad() :

```
self.tableView.emptyDataSetSource = self;
self.tableView.emptyDataSetDelegate = self;
```

the following error appeared:

```
[UITableView setEmptyDataSetSource:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

i know it is coming from the first line but the second also of course gives the same error, any help?

Comment: Did you do `@interface YourControllerClass : YourControllerParentClass <DZNEmptyDataSetSource, DZNEmptyDataSetDelegate>` ?

Comment: yea: @interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIApplicationDelegate,DZNEmptyDataSetSource, DZNEmptyDataSetDelegate >